# Numbers which are writable as a sum of permutation pairs

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

We say that $N$ is writable as a sum of permutation pair $\{a,b\}$ if $a+b=N$, $a\neq b$ and $a$ and $b$ are permutations of each other (e.g. $321 = 156 + 165 = 147 + 174 = ... $).

Looking at 3-digit numbers, 386 of them are writable as a sum of permutations.

> 1. What is the density of numbers which are writable as a sum of permutations? Does it go to $1$ as $N$ increases?

Another interesting question is the number of different permutations that a number can be written as.

Looking at 3 digit numbers:

- $321$ is writable as sum of 5 different permutation pairs.
- $666$ is writable as sum of 7 different permutation pairs.
- $888$ is writable as sum of 10 different permutation pairs.

And for 4 digits:

- $5555$ is writable as sum of 28 different permutation pairs.
- $7777$ is writable as sum of 58 different permutation pairs.
- $9999$ is writable as sum of 96 different permutation pairs.

> 2.What is the best upper bound we can give on the number of different number permutation pairs that sums up to $N$? ($\frac{N}{2}$ is trivial, is there a better bound?)

Comment: Surely every even number is a sum of a permutation pair; $2n=n+n$  --- the identity is a permutation! If you mean to exclude the identity permutation, you should explicitly say so in the body of the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - You are correct, I meant different a,b, I'll edit the question, thanks.

Comment: Do you allow leading zeroes? E.g., $101=100+001$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson - yes, leading zeros are fine.

Comment: Then aren't there more than 10 pairs for 888? $840+048,741+147,642+246,543+345,804+084,714+174,624+264,534+354,480+408,471+417,462+426,453+435$

Comment: Hmm, you are correct @GeryMyerson, it seems I didn't count ones with leading zeros after all. In any case, either variant is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If carry is not allowed, better bound would be $5* 9^{\lceil log_{10}^n\rceil - 1}$ + some delta. But, what happens when carry is there in addition?